# Fill modal window form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am having trouble with populating modal window form. For example, I click on grid row for editing user and I call ajax which returns me specific data of user.

Current code:

```
 <modal title="Uredi uporabnika" visible="showModal">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user_name">Ime</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
 </modal>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.openUserEditor = function(selected_user_id){
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:ajax,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
        },
        data:{
            action:'loadUserData',
            id:selected_user_id
        }
    }).success(function(data,status){
            $scope.userInfo = data.user_info;
            $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    });
}
```

Modal window code:

```
app.directive('modal', function(){
  return {
  template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
        '<div class="modal-content">' + 
          '<div class="modal-header">' + 
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title}}</h4>' + 
          '</div>' + 
          '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
        '</div>' + 
      '</div>' + 
    '</div>',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace:true,
  scope:true,
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;

    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      if(value == true)
        $(element).modal('show');
      else
        $(element).modal('hide');
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });
  }
};
});
```

I would apreciate any help, even if I am doing in on right way becouse I am new at Angular.

Comment: where and when are you calling the openUserEditor function?

Comment: on row click in table ` <td>
           <button class="btn" ng-click="openUserEditor(user.id)">
               Edit
           </button>
         </td>`

Comment: can you please check the $scope object in your success callback..?? Sometimes it is set to window, and not to the controller scope. Then, you can have a variable outside the api call, like, var self=this, and then use, this.userInfo.

Comment: I got object with user informations in scope

Comment: I'll try looking into it... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the input ID to populate the values:

```
$("#user_name").val(data.user_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution after millions of different trys and I've just put hands over my head.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" value="{{userInfo.u_name}}" />
```

So I had to add userInfo object and call that parameter u_name.

tnx Shivi for help anyway :D